# Images are being served up differently when using localhost vs when on my server

Tags: html, node.js, express

Images on my website are being displayed differently when using my locally hosted node server vs when using my remote hosted server

On my local hosted machine the images are showing up as text/plain type and everything seems to work perfectly. However, on my remote server they show as text/html which means they don't display as pictures. The weird thing is that the browser seems to identify that these are supposed to be images and shows that little picture icon in the top left of the area that the image is supposed to show. It's the icon browsers show when they cant display an image.

Opening any of these images via right clicking the icon and opening (or opening via the network tab on chromes inspect functionality), it shows up with a plain html page that says "Hello there!". I assume that comes from me setting the website up initially, although the source code to send that is long gone.

Accessing the images directly through a url does the same thing. The root file is __dirname/images/image.jpg.
So,

```
server-url/images/spider.jpg
```

gives "Hello there!" and

```
localhost:3000/images/spider.jpg
```

will give the image.

There is one image that links to an external picture outside of the website that displays perfectly on both local and server and shows as type jpeg.

I've tried setting the images folder as static, changing the images, creating data links and as many different ways of writing it as I can think of.

The only difference between the two servers source code is that my remote server is running both https and http servers vs my local machine running a bog standard http server.

This is the nodejs/express code I'm using on both local and remote servers for serving the images.

```
//images
app.get('/images/jag.jpeg', function (req, res) {
    res.status(200);
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/images/jag.jpeg');
});

app.get('/images/landscape.jpeg', function (req, res) {
    res.status(200);
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/images/landscape.jpeg');
});

app.get('/images/night.jpg', function (req, res) {
    res.status(200);
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/images/night.jpg');
});

app.get('/images/space.jpg', function (req, res) {
    res.status(200);
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/images/space.jpg');
});

app.get('/images/spider.jpg', function (req, res) {
    res.status(200);
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/images/spider.jpg');
});
```

And this is the html code

```
<div id = "slide-body">
    <div class = "container" id = "container">
        <ul>
            <li class = "active">
                <img src = "link-to-external-picture"></li>
            <li><img src = "images/jag.jpeg"></li>
            <li><img src = "images/landscape.jpeg"></li>
            <li><img src = "images/night.jpg"></li>
            <li><img src = "images/space.jpg"></li>
            <li><img src = "images/spider.jpg"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

As the only differences in the code is how the servers are setup, here is the code for those.

Remote server

```
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

// Certificate
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/serverurl/privkey.pem', 'utf8');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/serverurl/cert.pem', 'utf8');
const ca = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/serverurl/chain.pem', 'utf8');

const credentials = {
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate,
    ca: ca
};

//req and res stuff

// Starting both http & https servers
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpServer.listen(80, () => {
    console.log('HTTP Server running on port 80');
});

httpsServer.listen(443, () => {
    console.log('HTTPS Server running on port 443');
});
```

Local server

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');

var app = express();

//res and req stuff

app.listen(3000);
console.log('now listening on port 3000');
```

Apologies for the big wall of text, and thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: why are you not using the [static](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) middleware?

Comment: Did you check what `__dirname` looks like on your server vs. on your localhost?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone yeah I found that page and gave it a try, but unfortunately it didn't solve this particular issue. I'm brand new to all this stuff so I'm learning as I go along. I will look more into static middleware now though.

Comment: @alfasin I can confirm that __dirname points to the root folder on both server and localhost and that the path to images from there is correct.